# Remove all removed pages from wordpress

Tags: plugin-development, wp-insert-post

I am creating a plugin in wordpress and the thing I am trying to do is to create pages with code using `wp_insert_post`.
After creating each page and removing all of them the new page with the same slug is being created with this format `slug-number`.

My question is how can I remove the page entirely from wordpress and database so each time a page is being created the previous one be deleted completely and the new ones slug become just the slug I provide without any number attached at the end of slug?

Comment: have you try to delete definitively the old post before to create the new one ? another try would be to change the slug of the old post before to create the new one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use [`wp_delete_post()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_delete_post/) with second parameter set to `true`. The post will be completely deleted, not trashed.

```
// Use $args to get the pages you created previously
// See https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_pages/
$pages = get_pages( $args );

if( $pages ) {
    foreach( $pages as $page ) {
        wp_delete_post( $page->ID, true );
    }
}
```

After that, you can use `wp_insert_post()` to create a new post with a slug previously used.

It may worth to consider to update the post instead of delete and create a new one.

Comment: It does remove the post entirely but the slug still adds a number to the end.

I want the slug to reset too

Comment: You need to create the new post **after** removing the previous one. Tested and working here.